# Gradient calculation in RNN: Backpropagation through time (many to one - relationship)

Tags: deep-learning, gradient, recurrent-neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

this is not directly a programming related question, but I honestly don't know where else to ask (If you know a forum where this question might better fit, please tell me and I will ask there).

I am trying to have a deeper understanding of how Backpropagation through time (BPTT) works and I came across [this great article](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-3-backpropagation-through-time-and-vanishing-gradients/) with this Image below:

[image: BPTT]

I still struggle to understand how (for example) i get `ds_1 / ds_0`? I know it should be calculated based on the previous gradients but how exactly is it defined?

I have tried to reconstruct the image above with my own example and watched some tutorials to fill out a more detailed version of the image above:

[image: BPTT_2]

I think the first 3 equations in red are correct but i am not too sure on how it goes on.

Can someone tell me if the 2 dark equations for h_t-1 are correct?

And how is this connected to the above version?
Is `ds_3 / ds_2 = dL / dθ_h`?

Any help is much appreciated :D

Cheers,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand what a computational graph is and how backpropagation is calculated through chain rule of calculus. After that, you can deal with the idea as a black box as modern deep learning frameworks do the dirty work for you and let you focus on the big picture.

I believe these two videos will help you get the idea of computational graph and its mathematics.

[What is Backpropagation Really Doing?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ilg3gGewQ5U)

[Backpropagation Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8)